# What client-side web scripting languages are there other than JavaScript and VBScript?

Tags: html, browser, client-side

1. How many client-side scripting language implementations did you see except JavaScript and VBScript? Like: **`type="text/C++Script"`**, **`text/CSharpScript`**, **`text/oberonScript`**, etc.
2. How can I learn if my browser supports those languages?

Answer (score 18):

The only languages I have ever seen supported by web browsers in `<script>` elements are:

- JavaScript / JScript (which is ubiquitous)
- [Webassembly](https://webassembly.org/) (which is less of a language than a different target other languages can be compiled to) is [well supported](https://caniuse.com/wasm) today)
- VBScript (IE [10 and lower](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn384057%28v=vs.85%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) only)
- PerlScript (IE with a plugin from ActiveState only)
- Dart (in a [nonstandard build of Chromium](http://www.dartlang.org/tools/dartium/)) which is not intended for production use.

The [HTML 4 specification](https://www.w3.org/TR/html4/interact/scripts.html#h-18.2.1) gives examples of Tcl, but I've never heard of a browser that implemented this.

In any practical sense (for WWW development), JavaScript and Webassembly is the only (not really a) choice.

There are also various languages (e.g. Dart, TypeScript, ES6/7) which have translators to convert programs to (ES5 flavoured) JavaScript which can then run in browsers.

Answer (score -5):

1. Is already answered above.
2. If you want to learn if browser supports languages that you already know the best is to embed their small snippets into page or inject using `innerHTML` from JavaScript. These scripts should then set some global property like `window['scripts']['oberon']=true;` this way you will learn that language type was detected indeed.