# Does HTML work with any other language other than JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, html

Is there any other language which can be used with HTML in programming webpages other than JavaScript?

Thanks

Comment: it's like, i'm somewhat good in VB. Can I use VB?

Comment: No. Learn JavaScript. VB is only supported in IE, and at that only older versions

Comment: Yes, you can use VB. Should you? No.

Comment: Ok. Thanks! I have another question... Is there anything in HTML like.... to read JavaScript from a text file and then interpret it in another webpage?

Comment: Do you mean all Client-side programming languages?

Comment: There will be **[Dart](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dart_(programming_language))**, but only in *In the Dartium Browser (a version of the Chromium web browser modified to include a Dart virtual machine)*.

Comment: No. In general, when you are designing a webpage, instead of typing the code in the page itself, can you read the code from some other text file?

Comment: @Sandyman, you shouldn't ask multiple questions. This is a Q&A site not a forum. You can ask as many questions as you need and you can reference this original question but try and avoid discussions if you can. I would suggest a quick read of the [faq]

Comment: Possible quplicate [What client-side web scripting languages are there other than JavaScript and VBScript?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4434378/what-client-side-web-scripting-languages-are-there-other-than-javascript-and-vbs)

Answer (score 2):

As far as I understand your question we are talking for client-side language which is being interpreted by the browser, without additional plugin like JVM, flash player.

You can use a programming language which is compiled to JavaScript (CoffeeScript, Dart, JSX, TypeScript...) but the browser will interpret only JavaScript (except Internet Explorer which may supports VBScript and I guess Chrome which may be able to run Dart).

Answer (score 1):

Yes, in the mainstream there is VBScript *however* it's only supported by Internet Explorer.

Really though your question comes down to where your HTML will be rendered and whatever the host renderer supports.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, `CSS` is a language too. Then there are client-side technologies like Java and Flash too.

But why do you ask?

Web development uses server-side technologies like some PHP frameworks and ASP.NET, among other. On server-side coding you can program using C#, Java, PHP or a host of other languages, but they usually 'generate' HTML which is served to the client browser.

Does this answer your question?

Answer (score 0):

Well, on the server side, any language can be used.

In the browser, you need a plugin, which could be for Java or something more esoteric like  Tcl/Tk

Comment: Yes, but you don't mention that a plugin is required for Java to work in the browser, hence my assumption that you meant JavaScript

Comment: Perhaps the edit fixes this.  Thanks for making it clearer.

Comment: Today I learned `<applet>` is [deprecated and not part of HTML5](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/applet); not that I've used it in years....

Comment: Wahooo! that's a reason to celebrate! :)

Answer (score 0):

Yes. You're talking about client side scripting. And there are other languages that can do that. I'm not really up to date, but back in the day, ActivePerl (a Perl distribution by ActiveState) had a version that ran in Internet Explorer.

Answer (score -1):

You are referring to any form of client side Language which has to do with how you're browser interprets information.

Comment: What does that even mean?